# new project :: adv. contactbook , but i am facing some issues

Tags: python, file

i am a beginner at python , i was working with this project from a long time.

in this project the user should be able to create different account . and the account username and password should be kept in .txt file. then when the user wish they can create a contact book and then write some contact details. the user should also open the contact book whenever they want. but i am getting of error . so could somebody help me.

this is the codes --

```
name=(user2+".txt")

contact_book=open(name,"a")

contact_book.write("\n")
option=input("hello,do you want to save a new contact:(yes/no) ")
space=("                     ")

def openbook():
    option=input("do you want to open the contacts (yes/no)")
    if option == ("yes"):
        openfile=open(name,"r")
        print(space)
        openfile=openfile.read()
        print(openfile)
        contact_book.close()
    
def book():
    print("ok")
    name=input("what is the name?: ")
    print(space)
    phone=input("what is the phone number?: ")
    print(space)
    address=input("what is the address?: ")
   
    
    contact_book.write("\n")
    contact_book.write(name+"    "+phone+"    "+address)
    contact_book.write("\n")
    print("ok,done")
    print(space)
    contact_book.close()
    
    option1=input("do you want to save a new contact:(yes/no)")
    while option1==("yes"):
         book()
         
    if option1==("no"):
             openbook()    
        
x=2

while x==2:
   
    
  
    if option==("yes"):
        book()
        delete=input("do you want to delete the contact book!! (yes/no)")
        if delete == ("yes"):
            os.remove(name)
        
        
    
    if option ==("no"):
        openbook()
        delete=input("do you want to delete the contact book!! (yes/no)")
        if delete == ("yes"):
            os.remove(name)
        if delete==("no"):
            print("ok")
            input("")
        if delete == ("yes"):
            os.remove(name)
        x=x-2
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the question?

Comment: I ran the code. The only error is `name 'user2' is not defined` which is expected.